# Ruby on Rails convention to store big SQLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best practice to store big SQL queries in the Ruby on Rails?

How I'm doing now:

```
class SqlQueries
  CASHFLOW_DATES = <<SQL
SELECT * 1; // here is a big sql
SQL

# here is a lot of constants


  def self.run(name)
    sql = const_get(name.to_s.upcase)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
  end
end
```

SQL queries cannot be converted into the ARel code, and it's impossible to use views, because they are not sync with `schema.rb`.

Comment: perhaps give us an example of one of your current queries and where you're currently keeping it

Comment: @kyledecot added more details. Cannot add SQL here, because it's not about the SQL code, but about the code organization.

Comment: Why can't you use views exactly?

Comment: Because they will not sync with `schema.rb`, I will require to use `schema.sql` instead, which I don't want to use. Is there are any other conventions, rather than storing big SQLs in the database view?